# "The multi-part identifier 'xxx' could not be bound" when attempting to join three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, distinct

I'd like to start off with the fact that I'm a SQL beginner with only 5 or 6 hours of experience. I'm learning fast though.

Ultimately I am trying to select the addresses of clients by product line. The first table (arinvch) contains invoices and therefore the addresses of the clients; the second table (aritrsh) contains the individual line items of the invoices of table 1, and the third table (icitemh) contains the product lines of the line items.

I attempted to join tables two and three in a subquery first to extract the product lines, then join that with the first table to get the customer addresses by product line.

Simply put, this is what I tried to do:

```
SELECT
   table1.addressinfo
FROM
   table1 
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM
   table2 INNER JOIN table3
   ON table2.itemnumber = table3.itemnumber
   WHERE table3.type = 'CRM') joinedtable
ON 
   table1.customernumber = joinedtable.customernumber;
```

The exact code:

```
SELECT
  arinvch.ccustno AS [Customer #],
  arinvch.dinvoice AS [Invoice Date],
  arinvch.cbcompany AS [Bill to Company],
  arinvch.cbaddr1 AS [Bill to Address 1],
  arinvch.cbaddr2 AS [Bill to Address 2],
  arinvch.cbcity AS [Bill to City],
  arinvch.cbstate AS [Bill to State],
  arinvch.cbzip AS [Bill to Zip Code],
  arinvch.cbcountry AS [Bill to Country],
  arinvch.cbphone AS [Bill to Phone],
  arinvch.cscompany AS [Ship To Company],
  arinvch.csaddr1 AS [Ship To Address 1],
  arinvch.csaddr2 AS [Ship To Address 2],
  arinvch.cscity AS [Ship To City],
  arinvch.csstate AS [Ship To State],
  arinvch.cszip AS [Ship To Zip Code],
  arinvch.cscountry AS [Ship To Country],
  arinvch.csphone AS [Ship To Phone],
  arinvch.cscontact AS [Ship To Contact],
  aritrsh.cinvno AS [Invoice #],
  aritrsh.citemno AS [Item Number],
  icitemh.citemno AS [Item #]
FROM
  arinvch 
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT
  aritrsh.clineitem
  FROM 
  aritrsh 
  INNER JOIN 
  icitemh
  ON
  aritrsh.citemno = icitemh.citemno
  WHERE icitemh.ctype = 'CRM')table2
ON 
    arinvch.ccustno = aritrsh.ccustno;
```

This returns the following error message (in FlySpeed SQL):

[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The
multi-part identifier "aritrsh.ccustno" could not be bound.

Thanks in advance! 
(Also, as a side goal, if you could also explain how I can get the addresses to not repeat when I pull them from the invoices that would be great. I've tried incorporating SELECT DISTINCT in numerous places but can't seem to work out a solution (as I only want the table1.customernumber to be distinct and WHERE DISTINCT isn't a thing).)

Answer (score 0):

```
    arinvch 
    JOIN ( 
        SELECT aritrsh.clineitem
        FROM aritrsh 
            JOIN icitemh ON
                aritrsh.citemno = icitemh.citemno
        WHERE icitemh.ctype = 'CRM'
        ) table2 ON 
        arinvch.ccustno = aritrsh.ccustno;
```

the second table is table2 in your example, not aritrsh.

For the second part: 
arinvch (1:M) -> aritrsh and 
aritrsh (1:1) -> icitemh

aritrsh will have 1 or more products ordered by customers.  This will repeat the address fields for each product ordered.  You could summarize the entire thing by putting the entire select statement in parentheses then use group by to remove the invoice records.

```
select a, b, c, d
from ( big select statement above ) A
group by a, b, c, d
```

the group by will remove duplicates (just like distinct.) Replace a,b,c,d with the names of your fields in the inner select without prefixes like aritrsh., but only have the fields that have to do with the address and the products, not the invoice lines.

Comment: I corrected my mistake there and replaced aritrsh.ccustno with table2.ccustno. Unfortunately, the following error popped up: [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'ccustno'.

Comment: I can assure you ccustno is indeed a column name in our SQL server present in arinvch and aritrsh.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subquery:

```
FROM arinvch INNER JOIN
     aritrsh
     ON arinvch.ccustno = aritrsh.ccustno INNER JOIN
     icitemh
     ON aritrsh.citemno = icitemh.citemno AND icitemh.ctype = 'CRM'
```

The logic is simpler to understand without subqueries.  I would use table aliases for the query:

```
FROM arinvch n INNER JOIN
     aritrsh t
     ON n.ccustno = t.ccustno INNER JOIN
     icitemh i
     ON t.citemno = i.citemno AND i.ctype = 'CRM'
```

These make it easier to write and read the query.

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work. No errors popped up upon execution of the code however no records showed up either. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Start with one join and then add more.  Apparently, the data in the tables doesn't match.